# how to set backroundcolor

Tags: apache-flex, colors, tabbar

Is there a way to set a common Backgroundcolor for all the tabs in a given TabBar?

Rightnow I am able to set color only for selected tabs using

> tabBar.getChildAt and setStyle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give them all a common `styleName` and set the backgroundColor style in CSS.

MXML

```
<mx:TabNavigator width="100%" height="100%">
    <mx:VBox label="Tab 1" styleName="tabContainers"></mx:VBox>
    <mx:VBox label="Tab 2" styleName="tabContainers"></mx:VBox>
    <mx:VBox label="Tab 2" styleName="tabContainers"></mx:VBox>
</mx:TabNavigator>
```

CSS:

```
.tabContainers
{
    backgroundColor: #ff0000;
}
```